# JS: how to update quantity that comes from an endpoint without constantly making a request?

Tags: javascript

I have a backend endpoint that returns a product and the inventory for each product variant.  On the customer facing side, I refresh this every X-seconds so that the customer sees the update to date quantity.  Is there a way I can do this without having to continually poll this endpoint to detect changes?

Comment: Have you ever considered using a socket endpoint for this? pure WebSocket API or socket.io are the simplest ways.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using http polling, which requires the client to initiate a request. You could use websockets, so a message wouls only be sent from the server to the client, whenever the server sees fit. This option is preferable as it preserves bandwith.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: I never actually used Pusher, but Pusher uses WebSockets if it can. If it cannot, it falls back to http. If it does fallback, I would assume that it then does similiar polling, but I don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound obvious but if you can implement websockets on your backend API, then you can listen to the updates in realtime, and update only when the quantity changes.

However, if for some reason, you don't have control over the backend, you can optimize your polling code by only polling when the user is on your site using `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus`.